# Copy field value to another field

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to hide `form.title` field and set the `form.title` field value to `form.oro_eventname`. 
The user only can see `form.oro_eventname`, but the value of `form.oro_eventname` is copied to `form.title`.

Can anyone show me how to do it?

```
{% set dataBlocks = [{
    'title': 'General Information'|trans,
    'class': 'active',
    'subblocks': [
        {
            'title': '',
                'data':  [
                form_row(form.title),
                form_row(form.oro_eventname),
                form_row(form.description),
                form_row(form.backgroundColor),
                form.calendarUid is defined ? form_row(form.calendarUid) : null,
                form_row(form.attendees),
                entity.recurrence is null ? form_row(form.reminders) : null,
                form_row(form.notifyAttendees),
                invitations.notify_attendees_component()
            ]
        },
        {
            'title': '',
            'data':  [
                '<div ' ~ UI.renderPageComponentAttributes(calendarEventDateRange) ~ '>' ~
                form_row(form.start) ~
                form_row(form.end) ~
                form_row(form.allDay) ~
                '</div>',
                form.recurrence is defined ? form_row(form.recurrence) : null
            ]
        }
    ]
}] %}
```

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what you want to do. Can you provide more details or maybe a picture of what you need?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that either with javascript (a function that trigger on keyup event for example)

```
$('#id_title').val() = $('#id_oro_eventname').val();
```

or in your controller

```
$title = $form->get('oro_eventname')->getData();
$yourEntity -> setTitle($title);
```

Comment: I would recommend the second way to avoid depending on the front-end code. Some people uses Javascript disabled to avoid advertising in some devices.

Comment: @MartinFasani I agree

Answer (score 0):

Set title field as nullable true in entity so, it will not through validation error for null value if you do not add title field in form.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $title;
```

In your add/edit action set title value if form is valid like this.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $event = $form->getData();
    $event->setTitle($event->getOroEventname());

    // Other code like persist flush redirect...
}
```